# Is there an IntelliJ plugin to publish pieces of code to Gist

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I like the gist plugin in Emacs which allows me to select a bit of code and publish it to gist.github.com so I can paste the link in a chat box to discuss with my colleagues.

I really like that for IntelliJ IDEA. Does anyone know of such a plugin?

Comment: Sadly last time I checked, there were no plugins for any pastebin integration in IntelliJ.

Comment: An alternative is using ideatalk, which is the chat client inside idea, assuming the people you send it to are using idea too. I think you can send code pointers too.

Comment: Yep, we're using that too, but this only works 1-1 not for groupchat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is for the time being : Nope, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You have been heard by the devteam: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/09/github-gists-are-here/